# Flash player update "install" does nothing on OS X

Tags: macos, adobe-flash

As seen in the screenshot the Flash Player update has been successfully downloaded and launched. The "Accept License Agreement" checkbox was clicked and the `Install` button was then enabled.

But clicking on the "Install" button does…***nothing***…

[image]
I am on `El Capitan`. Any hints here?

Comment: What messages are logged to the Console utility's "All Messages" log when you click Install?

Comment: @Spiff  Nothing new in the Console.

Comment: Same issue and here is what the console says:
17/05/2016 09:23:05.920 authd[154]: copy_rights: _server_authorize failed

Comment: Same problem on ElCapitan, nothing in logs.  Work around seems to be to do Check for Updates in System Prefs.  I get this error when the auto update check pops up, but running manually seems to work. The "for systems administrators" installers from here (http://www.adobe.com/sea/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html) also seem to work, but they're killing that page at the end of the month supposedly.